# Create unique cartesian product from a list

Tags: python

How do I create a cartesian product of a list itself with unique elements?

For example, `lists = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, and I want to create `[['a', 'b'], ['a','c'], ['b','c']]`.

Comment: That isn't a Cartesian product -- it is a set of combinations. Just use `itertools.combinations(lists,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations
lists = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(list(map(list, combinations(lists,2))))
```